# Sequelize hasMany association not working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, associations

I have a Product model:

```
   module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
       const Product = sequelize.define("product", {
          SKU: {
             type: Sequelize.STRING,
          },
          name: {
             type: Sequelize.STRING,
          },
          description: {
             type: Sequelize.TEXT,
          },
          categoryID: {
             type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          }
       });
       Product.associate = function (models) {
          Product.hasMany(models.Stock, { foreignKey: 'productID', as: 'stocks' })
       };
       return Product;
    }
```

Which has a hasMany relation with the `Stock` model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
   const Stock = sequelize.define("stock", {
      note:  DataTypes.STRING,
      })
   Stock.associate = function (models) {
      Stock.belongsTo(models.Product)
   };
   return Stock;
}
```

When trying to query the Products, I get the following error:

```
exports.getAllAvailableProducts = (req, res) => {
      const queryParams = req.query;
      Product.findAll({
         include: ['stocks'],
         where: queryParams
      }).then((products) => {
         res.status(200).send(products);
      })
};


(node:58108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Association with alias "stocks" does not exist on product
```

Am i doing something wrong here? I don't see the FK appearing in my database either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
       const Product = sequelize.define("product", {
          SKU: {
             type: Sequelize.STRING,
          },
          name: {
             type: Sequelize.STRING,
          },
          description: {
             type: Sequelize.TEXT,
          },
          categoryID: {
             type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          }
       });
       Product.associate = function (models) {
          // models.stock is correct
          Product.hasMany(models.stock, { foreignKey: 'productID', as: 'stocks' })
       };
       return Product;
    }
```

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
   const Stock = sequelize.define("stock", {
      note:  DataTypes.STRING,
      })
   Stock.associate = function (models) {
      // models.product is correct
      //Stock.belongsTo(models.product)
      Stock.belongsTo(models.product, {
          foreignKey: 'productId',
          as: 'product'
    })
   };
   return Stock;
}
```

models/index.js

```
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
   host: dbConfig.HOST,
   dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
   operatorsAliases: false,

   pool: {
      max: dbConfig.pool.max,
      min: dbConfig.pool.min,
      acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
      idle: dbConfig.pool.idle
   }
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.user = require("./user.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.category = require("./category.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.product = require("./product.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.orderline = require("./orderline.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.order = require("./order.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.stock = require("./stock.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);

// we need call associate function
db.stock.associate(db)
db.product.associate(db);

module.exports = db;
```

```
    Product.findAll({
         include: ['stocks'],
         where: queryParams
      }).then((products) => {
         res.status(200).send(products);
      })
```

Comment: or, please check `https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize`, there is many examples there

Comment: i found the main problems, the `models/index.js` is not enough to run `associate function`

Comment: Whats missing in the index?

Comment: `Product.hasMany(models.stock`, and  `index.js : db.stock.associate(db);  db.product.associate(db);` is main problems

Comment: Got it! So you need to load the associations for each model, seems like a lot of redundancy... Would be great if there was a way to enable it for all models

Comment: please use `https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize/blob/master/models/index.js`

Comment: Adding the belongsTo in the Stock actually gives me an error, the hasMany on its own works though

Comment: belongsTo need `forieginKey`, `as`, so, i updated my answer

Comment: That fixed it! Now I need to find a way to place the productID row before the createdAt and updatedAt..